# libcurl ftp upload is very slow

Tags: c++, c, curl, ftp, libcurl

I'm writing a c++ program that uploads directories with thousands of small files in them. I use libcurl library to do the uploading, but it's very slow. I experimented to upload a directory with 1500 files. My program spends half an hour while ftp mput spends only two minutes. The code is as follow. How can I make my program as fast as ftp mput?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#endif

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    if (ac != 3) {
        return 1;
    }

    std::string ip = av[1];
    std::string local_path = av[2];
    if (local_path[local_path.size() - 1] == '/')
    {
        local_path = local_path.substr(0, local_path.size() - 1);
    }

    std::string folder;
    std::size_t found = local_path.rfind("/");
    if (found != std::string::npos) {
        folder = local_path.substr(found + 1);
    }
    else {
        folder = local_path;
    }

    struct dirent *dirst;
    DIR *dp = opendir(local_path.c_str());
    while ((dirst = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        std::string name = dirst->d_name;
        if (name == "." || name == "..")
        {
            continue;
        }

        std::string url;
        url += "ftp://" + ip + "/" + folder + "/" + name;
        printf("%s\n", url.c_str());
        std::string file = local_path + "/" + name;

        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;
        FILE *hd_src;
        struct stat file_info;
        curl_off_t fsize;

        /* get a FILE * of the same file */
        hd_src = fopen(file.c_str(), "rb");

        /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

        /* get a curl handle */
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {

            /* enable uploading */
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

            /* specify target */
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "ingest:upload");

            /* now specify which file to upload */
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS, 1L);

            /* Now run off and do what you've been told! */
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            /* Check for errors */
            if (res != CURLE_OK)
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

            /* always cleanup */
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        fclose(hd_src); /* close the local file */

        curl_global_cleanup();

    }

    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For one, this will upload *one* file at a time. Check your net stat on your mput, as I'll bet your lunch that it is open dozens, or even hundreds, of concurrent connections. The curl multi interface is probably better suited for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: With ftp mput, you connect once to the remote server and use that sole connection to transfer all the files. Your current code uses one different connection per file. If you want to have the same speed, you must reuse the existing connection.

Comment: You should use threads to do so

Comment: Thanks all. ftp mput uses one connection for all the files. I found the solution to libcurl here https://schneide.blog/2017/10/02/keeping-connections-alive-with-libcurl/.  Getting curl_easy_init() out of the loop makes the connection reusable.